# Loop behaves oddly in I2C receiveEvent

Tags: i2c

I am messing around with an ATmega328P hooked on a Raspberry Pi, communicating over I2C. The ATmega is the slave (details at the end). While testing the basics of the concept, I faced an interesting problem.

This is the code on the ATmega:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

#define SLAVE_ADRESS 0x1A
#define LED 6

int count = 10;
void setup()
{
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
    /*for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
    {
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
      delay(100);
    }*/
    Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADRESS);
    Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
    Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
}

void loop()
{
  delay(10);
}

void receiveEvent(int received_bytes)
{
  while(Wire.available())
  {
    unsigned char i = Wire.read();
    if(1)
    {
      int j = 5;
      while(j>0)
      {
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        delay(300);
        j-=1;
      }
    }
    delay(1);
  }
}

void requestEvent()
{
  Wire.write(count);
}
```

What you would expect it to do is blink the LED connected to pin 6 five times when the Pi sends a byte to the ATmega slave. (Things like `if(1)` are there because the code was much more specific originally.) The strange thing is that this is not the case:

*The LED only blinks 1 time.*

I honestly have no idea why. This "stdio-fitted" version of the problematic loop ran on the RPi as expected, prints 5*2 times:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int j = 5;
  while(j>0)
  {
    printf("LED, HIGH\n");
    printf("LED, LOW\n");
    j-=1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Circumstances:**

- I compile the code in the Arduino IDE on the Pi, then upload it
  using AVRDUDE to the ATmega with the Pi's GPIOs. No error messages
  over the process.
- The ATmega gets 3.3 V supply voltage from the Pi, and operates on
  16.000 MHz. Only the LED and the Pi is connected to it.
- The (Python) code I use on the Pi to write and read a byte is the following. Reading works well, and I know by tests that the ATmega actually receives the correct byte:

```python
import pigpio
import time

pi = pigpio.pi()
atmega = pi.i2c_open(1, 0x1A)

for i in range(6):
    a = pi.i2c_read_byte(atmega)
    print a

pi.i2c_write_byte(atmega, 0x05)
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Side note. Better use `for(;;)` for controlling loops. Just one clear instruction vs three unrelated ones. Example: `for (int j=5; j > 0; j--)` do the same, it's shorter and express your intention clearly to any other programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```C++
void receiveEvent(int received_bytes)
{
  while(Wire.available())
  {
    unsigned char i = Wire.read();
    if(1)
    {
      int j = 5;
      while(j>0)
      {
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        delay(300);
        j-=1;
      }
    }
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

`receiveEvent` is an ISR (interrupt service routine). Don't do `delay` in an ISR. That will hang indefinitely. Thus the LED only blinks once. You could do `delayMicroseconds` for *testing*. In general an ISR should be **short**.

---

- [Interrupts](http://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts)
- [I2C](http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c)

Comment: Thank you! So I should move as much as possible to the main loop from an ISR, or only avoid timed functions?

Comment: It is valid to receive the data in the ISR (make the global variable (buffer) `volatile`). After that, set a flag (also `volatile`) and do the rest in the main loop.

Comment: `I should move as much as possible to the main loop from an ISR` - yes you should.